# Prevent R from executing code in R profile when installing packages

Tags: r

I have some code in my R profile that I've found interferes with package installation. For example, I like to automatically load devtools when I'm working on packages, so I have this

```
if (file.exists("DESCRIPTION")) {
    try({suppressMessages(library(devtools))})
}
```

However, I've found that this interferes with package installation, I get errors like `ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rlang’`. If I comment out the loading of devtools in the R profile, the package installs without error.

Is there any way to check if .Rprofile is being executed during package installation so that I could put that condition in the if and stop devtools from loading at inappropriate times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d generally recommend against putting such code into your `~/.Rprofile`! — The `~/.Rprofile` should contain only *general* configuration that is always valid. For further customisation, use a project-local `~/.Rprofile` instead.

However, I would make one exception to the above guideline, because one useful distinction you can make is to only execute certain code in interactive sessions:

```
if (interactive()) {
    if (file.exists("DESCRIPTION")) {
        try({suppressMessages(library(devtools))})
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, that works! One note though - I've tried to put it into the local .Rprofile, but then the code also runs during package installation if you happen to install packages in that project.

Answer (score 0):

.Rprofile files are sourced on R startup. They won't be called later by other functions so you can't use the checking logic during `install.packages()`.

For this reason loading packages using RProfile is not always advisable as it can make your code non-reproducible. However, as a helper package, devtools is probably a good exception (ignoring your particular problem here).

If you use base R only you can tell R not to load Rprofile during startup by using the --vanilla or --no-init-file arguments.

If you are using RStudio one workaround would be to use project level Rprofile files. Rstudio starts a new R session for each project, and loads the user Rprofile from the project root. If it then can't find that it will attempt to load the user RProfile.

- Create a new project and within the the project options tick the option to disable the Rprofile loading.
- Whenever you want to install a package switch to this project.

One caveat is to make sure you are running this as the only project session open, having multiple RStudio sessions open when installing new packages can lead to problems without putting the Rprofile in the mix.

Rstudio article on startup files https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf

Base R documentation on R initialization https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html

A diagram of the R startup flow and some commentary on use of renviron and rprofile
https://rstats.wtf/r-startup.html

Comment: Two notes: (1) project-level `.Rprofile` files aren’t a feature of RStudio, they are a feature of R itself. So you don’t need RStudio to use this functionality. (2) Using `--vanilla` or `--no-init-file` is only advisable in exceptional cases, because often the user profile contains necessary configuration (e.g. it might configure the library path; this could also be configured elsewhere, in particular via environment variables, but there are scenarios where it needs to be configured in the user profile).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Most references to R projects I can find mean R Studio (capital P) Projects. While I assume you can create a specific 'project' directory structure, place a Rprofile and/or Renviron file within it and start R at that location; it is not called  a project in the general literature (that I can find). Is there another way to create projects? RStudio is my IDE of choice so I'm rather ignorant of other workflows methods.

Comment: Having a directory which contains all the code (and potentially data) for some (lower-case) project has been called a “project” before RStudio even existed. This isn’t even specific to R, but the terminology definitely also exists for R outside of RStudio. It’s just that most (good) recent learning resources for R are focussed on RStudio as a beginner-friendly editor. Still, it’s important to remind people that RStudio isn’t the only way to work with R.